# Jenkins Helm Chart with AD Integration

Tags: jenkins, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy Jenkins with Helm chart in EKS with AD integration.

I deployed Jenkins and able to login with user name password, but not getting how to add the root Cert, which is required for ldaps integration.

How to add the root cert to Jenkins helm chart?

Comment: I was using below configuration , and its not working since i did not updated the root cert                                                                                                                   securityRealm: |-
     ldap:
          configurations:
            - server: "ldaps://awsev1cttdc01.topp_company.wireless.ad:3455"
              rootDN: dc=acme,dc=uk
              groupMembershipStrategy:
                    fromUserRecord:
                      attributeName: "memberOf"

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link to configure Ldap in my Jenkins Helm chart `https://thomascfoulds.com/2020/03/10/ldaps-in-jenkins-on-k8s.html`

Our Organization ldap URL was having _ and the java version we used is 1.11. The java 1.11 won't accept the URLs with _ in ldap configuration.

We added below steps (last 2 steps) to make it work .

```
javaOpts: >
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/jenkins_keystore/keystore.jks
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
   Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true 
    -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldapURLParsing="legacy"
```

Ldap Settings in Helm chart are

```
securityRealm: |-
      ldap:
        configurations:
          - server: "ldaps://url.topp_orgname.ad:portNumber"
            rootDN: DC=TOPP_TELECOM,DC=WIRELESS,DC=AD
            managerDN: "managerLdapUsername"
            managerPasswordSecret: "managerLdapPassword"
            userSearch: "sAMAccountName={0}"
            groupSearchFilter: "(objectCategory=Group)"
```